# Advice for tool or a script to report a step by step Python file execution

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's consider the small script above.

```
def d(n):
    if n==0:
        return 0

    else:
        return d(n−1)

print d(3)
```

Is there tool that can report each step action as a debugger can do ?

Comment: Did you look at the `pdb` (Python debugger) module yet?

Comment: I'll try it. My purpose would be to automate the report...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  [Winpdb - A Platform Independent Python Debugger](http://winpdb.org/) to step through the execution of the script while reviewing the value of each variable at each step, and follow the flow of instructions.

Another option is to use the [trace](http://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html) module.

```
$ python -m trace --trace test.py 
 --- modulename: threading, funcname: settrace
threading.py(90):     _trace_hook = func
 --- modulename: t, funcname: <module>
t.py(1): def d(n):
t.py(6): print d(3)
 --- modulename: t, funcname: d
t.py(2):     if n==0:
t.py(5):         return d(n-1)
 --- modulename: t, funcname: d
t.py(2):     if n==0:
t.py(5):         return d(n-1)
 --- modulename: t, funcname: d
t.py(2):     if n==0:
t.py(5):         return d(n-1)
 --- modulename: t, funcname: d
t.py(2):     if n==0:
t.py(3):         return 0
0
```

Comment: I'll try it. My purpose would be to automate the report...

Comment: Great ! I'll simply use it via a subprocess.